# How could they stone with esrogim without a court case?

Tags: sukkot, beit-din-court, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, capital-punishment, masechet-sukkah

The mishnah in Sukkah ([48b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=48b&format=pdf)) tells of a [Tzadukki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadducees) who, on Sukkot, performed a service in the temple incorrectly and all the people in the temple stoned him to death with their esrogim. I would like to know how they were halachically allowed to do so instead of taking him to court and having the normal proceedings of a halachic capital case.

Comment: I don't recall anything in the Torah about stoning Tzedukim with Ethrogim. Maybe they weren't following protocol so closely on the court proceedings, either.

Comment: Yoma 26 also talks about the etrog-pelting but doesn't say they stoned him to death.  I see the same language on Sukkah 48, but I'm relying on translation so maybe something was lost?  (Can etrogim even *be* fatal?)

Comment: To your last point, @MonicaCellio, doubtless they can be fatal. The _bes hamikdash_ was *crowded* on _Sukos_. The fellow may have had an [eggshell skull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggshell_skull), too, I suppose.

Comment: @MonicaCellio even if they were not those who threw them would be chayav for damages!

Comment: @pleaseremovemyaccount if there are damages, yes.  I've never been pummeled by etrogim so I have to use my imagination, but it seems more like bumps & bruises & a dry-cleaning bill, y'know?  (Though I grant the eggshell-skull possibility.)  The question seems to assume that (a) this caused death and also (b) it was a halachically-proper response rather than a mob acting in the heat of the moment, and I'm not so sure either applies.

Comment: @MonicaCellio See Rashi toward the bottom, that one of the altar's horns was damaged "by the *stones* they threw at it". Perhaps Rashi is bothered by the same thing as you.

Comment: @pleaseremovemyaccount what is the penalty for intentionally miscarrying the service? Would not be surprised if it was heavenly death, as we see by Nadab and Abihu, and we also see humans taking an active role in heavenly death by wy of kippot in Sanhedrin. Also, you are allowed to damage someone to prevent them from sinning. Perhaps the people were pelting him in the hope that he would stop pouring the water on his feet and pour it down the funnel.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a capital offense to perform a service in the temple incorrectly. So you don't have to assume that he was killed.

That said, the Mishna in Sanhedrin [פרק ט - משנה ו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01309.html#HtmpReportNum0058_L2) mentions that if a Cohen performed the service while impure - the punishment for which is lashes by Bet Din - the *Cohen Youth Movement*  would remove him from the temple and bash his head in with wooden sticks.

> כֹּהֵן שֶׁשִּׁמֵּשׁ בְּטֻמְאָה, אֵין אֶחָיו הַכֹּהֲנִים מְבִיאִין אוֹתוֹ לְבֵית דִּין, אֶלָּא פִרְחֵי כְהֻנָּה מוֹצִיאִין אוֹתוֹ חוּץ לָעֲזָרָה וּמַפְצִיעִין אֶת מֹחוֹ בִּגְזִירִין‏

So there is a precedent for *the enraged* to kill somebody who doesn't do the service correctly.

There are actually 3 other cases in that Mishna of people who are killed by *the enraged* rather than being punished by Bet Din:

> הַגּוֹנֵב אֶת הַקַּסְוָה וְהַמְקַלֵּל בַּקּוֹסֵם וְהַבּוֹעֵל אֲרַמִּית, קַנָּאִין פּוֹגְעִין בּוֹ

- One who steals a temple vessel
- One who curses the Lord with the name of an idol
- One who has marital relations with a non-Jewess

So the concept of extra-Bet-Din execution by *the enraged* is not unheard of in Judaism.

Comment: Looks like a comment not an answer. If a user is enraged by this, he can't kill you :) because the halakhot of kannain pogin bo are strictly delineated, luckily. They do not include the case at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Avodah Zarah 26b:

> המינין והמסורות והמומרים היו מורידין ולא מעלין
>
> Heretics, informers, and sinners to anger Hashem - we kill them and do not save them.

As the Kohen showed that he's a Tzeduki, he qualifies as a heretic and therefore may be killed without a court case.